# How do I remove Sprites when they go on a specific position?

Tags: java, libgdx, position, sprite

My Sprite are spawned at a random time, after being spawned the the move upward until they get on a certain position then they should be removed. That's what I've been trying to do but I always get an error.

```
//this method is called at random time
 public void newEnemy(){
        Sprite enemy= Pools.obtain(Sprite.class);
        enemy.set(enemySpr);
        enemy.setPosition(200,150);
        enemies.add(enemy);
    }



//removing the enemy
 while (enemyIterator.hasNext()){
  Sprite nextEnemy=enemyIterator.next();//<--error here,this is line 66  
           if(enemySpr.getY()+enemySpr.getHeight()>=treeObj.treeSpr.getY()){
               removeEnemy(nextEnemy);
           }
       }



//removeEnemy method
public void removeEnemy(Sprite sprite){
        enemies.remove(sprite);
        Pools.free(sprite);
    }



//this is the error there I get:

Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
   at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:901)
   at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:851)
   at com.dreamroad.savethetree.EnemyClass.update(EnemyClass.java:66)
   at com.dreamroad.savethetree.MyGdxGame.render(MyGdxGame.java:51)
   at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:215)
   at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:120)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I think this is the reason why I get the error, but I'm not sure:

```
public void draw(SpriteBatch batch){
        for(Sprite drawEnemy:enemies) {    //enemies is the ArrayList
            drawEnemy.draw(batch);
            drawEnemy.translateY(deltaTime * movement);
        }
    }
```

Comment: can i see the code for these functions?

 com.dreamroad.savethetree.EnemyClass.update(EnemyClass.java:66)
  com.dreamroad.savethetree.MyGdxGame.render(MyGdxGame.java:51)

Comment: this is for the line 51:  enemyObj.update(sr);   //basically I'm just calling the method with the error on the main render method (sr is the ShapeRenderer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Subler says, the problem here is that you're trying to remove something from a list at the same time as iterating over it.

However, there's an easier solution. Simply call remove() on the iterator. This will remove the iterator's current element.

```
//removing the enemy
while (enemyIterator.hasNext()) {

    Sprite nextEnemy = enemyIterator.next();
    if(enemySpr.getY() + enemySpr.getHeight() >= treeObj.treeSpr.getY()) {
        enemyIterator.remove();
        Pools.free(nextEnemy);
    }
}
```

Comment: But you cant do //enemyIterator.remove(nextEnemy);   //when the nextEnemy is inside the parameter I get an error, it cannot be applied on the iterator.

Comment: @StormAsdg Just change it to `enemyIterator.remove();`. And sorry, by the way. I think you got `removeEnemy` method from my answer to a previous question of yours, but I didn't consider that it might be called from an iterator.

Comment: Whoops! Sorry about that spurious parameter to remove() - I was in a hurry. I'll edit...

Comment: @Tenfour04 thanks for the second time, I just changed the condition to //nextEnemy>=700; cause I get error from the above one, and also I didn't realize that the iterator should have been updated every frame, that was also one of the reasons why I got the error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that youre trying to remove something in a list you're currently iterating over, the thing i've always done in a situation like this is create an extra list which holds the Sprites that should be deleted, and then delete them after iterating over the list (or, at the end of your update method, or something like that)

A short code sample that illustrates my idea:

```
//removing the enemy
//Initialize a list to store the sprites to be removed
List<Sprite> toBeRemovedSprites = new ArrayList<Sprite>();
while (enemyIterator.hasNext()){
    Sprite nextEnemy=enemyIterator.next(); //I get the error here..<--
    if(enemySpr.getY()+enemySpr.getHeight()>=treeObj.treeSpr.getY()){
        removeEnemy(nextEnemy);
        toBeRemovedSprites.add(nextEnemy);
    }
}
//Remove the sprites that should be deleted, after iterating over the list
for(Sprite s : toBeRemovedSprites){
    enemies.remove(s);
}



//removeEnemy method
public void removeEnemy(Sprite sprite){
    //Remove this line that removes the sprite from the list
    //enemies.remove(sprite);
    Pools.free(sprite);
}
```

Another thing you could do is just to use the remove function of the iterator, 
imagine it could look something like this:

```
//removing the enemy
while (enemyIterator.hasNext()){
    Sprite nextEnemy=enemyIterator.next(); //I get the error here..<--
    if(enemySpr.getY()+enemySpr.getHeight()>=treeObj.treeSpr.getY()){
        removeEnemy(nextEnemy, enemyIterator);
    }
}



//removeEnemy method
public void removeEnemy(Sprite sprite, Iterator<Sprite> enemyIterator){
    //Change the line to remove using the iterator
    //enemies.remove(sprite);
    enemyIterator.remove();
    Pools.free(sprite);
}
```